# NextJs [Typescript, SCSS] Module not found

Tags: typescript, webpack, sass, next.js

I'm swapping a Next.js application from .js to .ts, and using ScSS, which seems to the the first error I get on `npm run dev`. It seems when I run `npm run build` I get some issues unrelated to scss though, so might be a wider issue.

Would really appreciate any suggestions?

**Swapping from js to ts**

```
touch tsconfig.json
npm run dev
npm install --save-dev typescript @types/react @types/node\n
npm run dev
```

**[ERROR]: NPM RUN DEV**
and I get the following errors on `npm run dev`:

```
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir '/Users/Edward.Martin/Desktop/Edward/projects/coinGift/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/util/util.js'
error - ./src/pages/_app.js:2:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'styles/global.scss'
  1 | import React from "react";
> 2 | import "styles/global.scss";
  3 | import "styles/components/index.scss";
  4 | import NavbarCustom from "components/NavbarCustom";
  5 | import Footer from "components/Footer";
```

**[ERROR]: NPM RUN BUILD**

```
Failed to compile.

./src/pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'styles/global.scss' in '/Users/Edward.Martin/Desktop/Edward/projects/coinGift/src/pages'

./src/pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'styles/components/index.scss' in '/Users/Edward.Martin/Desktop/Edward/projects/coinGift/src/pages'

./src/pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/NavbarCustom' in '/Users/Edward.Martin/Desktop/Edward/projects/coinGift/src/pages'

./src/pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/Footer' in '/Users/Edward.Martin/Desktop/Edward/projects/coinGift/src/pages'

./src/pages/_app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'util/analytics' in '/Users/Edward.Martin/Desktop/Edward/projects/coinGift/src/pages'


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

**Failed Solutions**

**Adding a scss declaration**
Most articles say to add a module definition into `next-env.d.ts`, but this just gets overriden (and it's clear this is no longer the solution as there's a comment in that file `// NOTE: This file should not be edited`)

I've added a `index.d.ts` into the root directory, with the following contents:

```
declare module "*.module.css";
declare module "*.module.scss";
declare module "*.scss" {
  const content: { [key: string]: any };
  export = content;
}
```

as well as adding `"index.d.ts"` into the `include` section of `tsconfig.json`

**Installing Other Dependancies**

```
npm i style-loader, css-loader, typescript
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, weird, I just checked the difference between the existing `jsconfig.json` and the `tsconfig.json`

It turns out I needed to add:

```
    "baseUrl": "./src",
```

Answer (score 0):

This did not work for me. Adding:

```
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
```

In my tsconfig.json did the job.